# Outlook 2016 - Can the default location for "Look in" be changed to "User Templates in File System" when choosing a template?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, templates

When using templates in Outlook, the default place that Outlook has in its "Look in" window is "Standard Forms Library". I use a lot of custom templates but I have to manually choose "User Templates in File System" to get to them. Is there a way to change this? I've searched the registry but came up blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a lot of testing and research, but I didn't find a way to change the default location displayed of "look in". But as far as I know, it is the most convenient to double-click to open the mail template.

If you like, as a workaround, please try to save the template on your computer desktop or in a frequently used folder, and then each time you want to use the template, just need double-click to open the template.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Yeah, looks like the best way is to just save the templates to the desktop or save a custom item on the ribbon. The Custom ribbon still requires keying down to "User Created Templates", but it works.